# FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken can not use after Xcode update to 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

After Xcode update to 8
my `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` didn't work.

I try update FacebookSDK but not working.

Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
[FIRApp configure];
return YES;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation
        ];
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
[FIRApp configure];
return YES;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation
        ];
```

}

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
```

}

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
    [self loadFromCoreData];
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code of whatever you have tried until now?

Comment: Upvoting. Have the same issue here. currentAccessToken is always nil now. Was perfectly working before.